# Laravel 5.4 not found error for existing route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am receiving a not found error for an existing laravel route

**web.php**:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminPageController@home')->name('admin-home');});
```

And when I try to access **'/admin'** in the url it says that it is not found, but all other routes were working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem
It was that in the **/public** folder I had an **/admin** folder in which I placed my assets for the admin part of the site. I removed it and placed my assets inside **/css/admin** folder instead of **/admin/css** and the error was gone.